# Is there a way to clear rxjs timeout so that I can use retrywhen to retry an http request after allowing the user to login again without timing out?

Tags: angular, rxjs, timeout, retrywhen

If a user gets logged out by the server and the client still thinks that the user is logged in, I will get a `401` error code as expected. However I wish to temporarily "save" and retry the request that failed after the user has been prompted for their credentials and re-signed in. To do this I figured that `retrywhen` would be great, however when used in conjunction with `timeout` I start to have issues. I wish to get timeout errors on my client if any request takes longer than 10 seconds, however if the request fails with a `401` status and prompts the user for credentials, I wish to not have that observable error out on me due to a timeout.

I have tried creating and using a custom service which had a replaySubject so that I could modify the timeout and use switchmap to swap the currently subscribed base observable with the changed timeout value, however this is not specific to one single request due to it's service/singleton nature and would replay for all requests. (I'm sure there are other issues with taking this direction.

I have a super stripped down example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/await-user-input-changing-timeout?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-not-authorized.interceptor.ts) where my "wait for user input" is replaced with a delay to simulate the user taking longer than the rxjs timeout that was set.

I expect that I should be able to retry a failed httpRequest after a user successfully logs in without timing out and without saving anything to external state

Comment: It was recommended to me that I use a race() between the handled http request and an rxjs timer, however that did not work, as the timer only started after a response came back through the interceptor for some reason?